# " Nothing more expected -> " when running "do it" in Squeak

Tags: squeak

I'm trying to run some command split on several lines from the Workspace in Squeak 5.1

When it's on one line, like below, it works fine:

```
Perroquet new nom: 'Polly' ; vocabulaire: 'Screatch! Go away'; vocabulaire: 'give me food'; parle.
```

However, if I try to split it on several lines, with or without tabs, it doesn't run and adds "Nothing more expected ->" in the workspace

```
Perroquet new nom: 'Polly' ;
    vocabulaire: 'Screatch! Go away';
    vocabulaire: 'give me food'; parle.
```

after "do it":

```
Perroquet new nom: 'Polly' ;
    vocabulaire: 'Screatch! Go away';
     Nothing more expected ->vocabulaire: 'give me food'; parle.
```

In the doc that I'm using, the examples given seem to be able to split it without any trouble. Is that because of different version of Squeak? Am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select the whole expression so it is highlighted and then invoke the do-it command. Otherwise, only the text on the current line is attempted to be evaluated, which fails because there is no receiver before #vocabulaire: